# how to bind application with rules via http api?

Tags: webrtc, telephony

Documentation [HTTP API](http://voximplant.com/docs/references/httpapi/#toc-managing-applications) describe manipulation with applications

For exmple how to get binded rules:

```
https://api.voximplant.com/platform_api/GetApplications?...&with_rules=1
```

But how I can bind exists rule to exists application via HTTP API?

Comment: We are talking about the VoxImplant

Answer (score 1):

As I see rules can not be unbind and to bind to another application or binds with few applications simultaneously...

Answer (score 0):

Rule is pretty simple thing, so you can just use `/AddRule` and `/DelRule` to [manipulate them](http://voximplant.com/docs/references/httpapi/#toc-managing-rules).